# What do "$m$" and "$d$" mean in the formula $F(A,B,C,D) = \Sigma m(9,10,12) + d(3,5,6,7,11,13,14,15)$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

What do "$m$" and "$d$" mean here?

[image]

I know that "$\Sigma$" means sum of products but I do not know what "$m$" and "$d$" mean.

Please help.

Comment: Not standard notation, so far as I am aware.  Can you give more context?  Where does the question come from?

Comment: They look like functions of some kind. Without more information, we would only be guessing.

Comment: @Abhirammv The d represents the [don't care terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t-care_term) and m represents the min-terms which'll be in SOP form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the notation that comes along with a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) in *boolean algebras*.

$\sum m$ represents the *canonical disjunctive normal form* (CDNF) or *minterm canonical form*.

The numbers - called *minterms* - are the entries in the table that are 1.

The $d$ is used to indicate the don't-care entries.

Additionally $\prod M$ represents the *maxterm canonical form*, which identifies the entries that are 0.